# multiple parameters using POST with asp.net handler

Tags: asp.net, http-post

I want to send multiple parameters using POST to an asp.net handler. How is that possible or is there any other work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be simpler to use a GET request and URL parameters like:

http://localhost/MyHandler.ashx?Param1=1&Param2=2

You could the retrieve the values using the `Request.Params` collection like:

```
var param1 = Request.Params["Param1"];
var param2 = Request.Params["Param2"];
```

Is that feasible for your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Read

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/02/asp-net-mvc-preview-5-and-form-posting-scenarios.aspx